# Add inputs onclick jQuery with PHP involved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to write a script that will add inputs on click with jQuery/javascript.

But it doesn't work and I cann't find out why. Even console.log() doesn't show anything.

I am no master at jQuery, but it should work I think.

Here is my code

```
        <div id="wrap_inputs">
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $pocet; $i++) { ?>
          <div class="span2" id="span_group<?= $i; ?>">
            <label class="control-label" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px;"> <?= LANG_CAN_BE_LEFT_OUT; ?></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="can_be_left_out[<?= $i; ?>]">
            <input class="span2 m-wrap" name="word[<?= $i; ?>]" type="text" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORD; ?> <?= $i; ?>" style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[<?= $i; ?>][1]" type="text" id="n<?= $i; ?>_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">
            <input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[<?= $i; ?>][2]" type="text" id="n<?= $i; ?>_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">
            <input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[<?= $i; ?>][3]" type="text" id="n<?= $i; ?>_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">
            <input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[<?= $i; ?>][4]" type="text" id="n<?= $i; ?>_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">
            <input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[<?= $i; ?>][5]" type="text" id="n<?= $i; ?>_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  var counter = <?= $pocet; ?>;

  $("#addButton").click(function () { 

      var span2_group = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'span_group' + counter);

      span2_group.after().html('<label class="control-label" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px;"><?= LANG_CAN_BE_LEFT_OUT; ?>' +
        '<input type="checkbox" name="can_be_left_out[' + counter + ']">' +
        '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="word[' + counter + ']" type="text" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORD; ?> ' + counter + '" style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
        '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][1]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">' +
        '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][2]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">' +
        '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][3]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">' +
        '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][4]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">' +
        '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][5]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">'
      );

      span2_group.appendTo("#wrap_inputs");


      counter++;
  });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
    }   

    counter--;

    $("#span_group" + counter).remove();

});
```

Variable $pocet is number of inputs from first step sent via $_POST[].

Comment: Have you viewed your source code at `var counter =`?

Comment: I would think that `span2_group.after()` is undefined. Its not in the DOM yet

Comment: You should `span2_group.appendTo("#wrap_inputs");` FIRST

Answer (score 0):

.....

```
  var span2_group = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'span_group' + counter);

  // PUT IT IN THE DOM HERE
  span2_group.appendTo("#wrap_inputs");

  // NOW it is in the DOM, you can call after()
  span2_group.after().html('<label class="control-label" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px;"><?= LANG_CAN_BE_LEFT_OUT; ?>' +
    '<input type="checkbox" name="can_be_left_out[' + counter + ']">' +
    '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="word[' + counter + ']" type="text" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORD; ?> ' + counter + '" style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
    '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][1]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">' +
    '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][2]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">' +
    '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][3]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">' +
    '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][4]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">' +
    '<input class="span2 m-wrap" name="replace[' + counter + '][5]" type="text" id="n' + counter + '_n_slovo" placeholder="<?= LANG_WORDREPLACE; ?>">'
  );
```

......

Comment: Do you see div#span_group in there? add a console.log right after `$("#addButton").click(function () { `

Comment: just want to make sure your click handler is working